# Proving Logical Equivalence Involving Null Quantification

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic, quantifiers

$\mathbf {Theorem}.$ Suppose $x$ does not occur as a free variable in $A$ and the domain of discourse is non-empty. Then $\left(\forall xP(x)\right)$ $\lor$ $A$ $\iff$ $\forall x(P(x)\ \lor A)$.

$\it Proof.\ $$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $\left(\forall xP(x)\right)$ $\lor$ $A$. Then either $\forall xP(x)$ or $A$ is true.

Case 1. $\forall xP(x)$. Let $y$ be arbitrary. Since $P(x)$ is true for all $x$, it follows that $P(y)$ is true, and so $P(y) \lor A$ is true. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x(P(x) \lor A)$.

Case 2. $A$ is true. Let $y$ be arbitrary. Since $A$ is true, it follows that $P(y) \lor A$ is true. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x(P(x) \lor A)$.

Since these cases cover all the possibilities, we can conclude that $\left(\forall xP(x)\right)\lor A\Rightarrow\forall x\left(P(x)\lor A\right)$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $\forall x\left(P(x) \lor A\right)$. If $\forall xP(x)$, then of course $\left(\forall xP(x)\right) \lor A$. Now suppose $\lnot\forall x P(x)$. Then we can choose some object $x_{0}$ such that $\lnot P(x_{0})$. Since $\forall x\left(P(x) \lor A\right)$ and $x_{0}$ is an object in the domain, it follows that $P(x_{0})\lor A$ is true. Since $P(x_{0})$ is false and $\lnot P(x_{0})\Rightarrow A$, we can conclude by modus ponens that $A$ is true. Therefore, $\forall x\left(P(x)\lor A\right)\Rightarrow \left(\forall xP(x)\right)\lor A.\qquad \Box$

Comment: What are you asking? If you're asking whether the solution is valid, it looks good to me. Note that the assumption that the domain of discourse is nonempty is actually never used.

Comment: Yes, I was asking if my proof was valid.

Comment: You're right that the assumption that the domain of discourse is nonempty is not explicitly used in the proof, but I thought it was necessary in order to apply universal instantiation in case 1.

Comment: @NicholasCousar The assumption of nonemptiness is in fact unnecessary. Your proof goes through as is without it.

Comment: Universal Instantiation does not require that the *assumed* variable actually exists, only that it is arbitrary.

Comment: @GrahamKemp That exact stipulation of how to apply U.I. has caused me so much grief. And it's all due to the vague/ambiguous wording of some of the definition(s) employed in textbooks when I first learned about rules of inference. So, I appreciate your input and clarification.